# Parse Sort Query via another PFObject (Not locally)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

I Use parse-server version 2.2.25 and parse iOS SDK version 1.14.2

I would like sort all objects on my `Cart` on field `desc` of the object `Catalog`.

My Simplified Database Structure is :

***Catalog (Table)***

```
+--------------+--------------+
|idkey (String)| desc (String)|
+--------------+--------------+
|   1          |    a         |
|   2          |    b         |
|   3          |    c         |
+--------------+--------------+
```

***Cart (Table)***

```
+--------------+------------------------------+
|Qty (Number)  | Catalog (object -> PFObject) |
+--------------+------------------------------+
|   2          |            1                 |
|   2          |            2                 |
|   4          |            3                 |
+--------------+------------------------------+
```

I try many solutions without good solution.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Cart"];
[query includeKey:@"Catalog"];
[query addAscendingOrder:@"desc"];
         or
[query addAscendingOrder:@"Catalog.desc"];
```

So, I can't sort locally for 2 reasons :

1. Many records > 100.000
2. I use ParseUI (PFQueryTableViewController / PFQueryCollectionViewController), with pagination (25/40 record per page).

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, it's different!

Comment: No, it's different! This solution use a locally sort, but I need use a remote sort (in query) because I use PFQueryTableViewController (pagination)

Answer (score 0):

according to parse docs:

> Note that we do not, however, support GeoPoint or non-filtering
>   constraints (e.g. nearGeoPoint, withinGeoBox...:, limit, skip,
>   orderBy...:, includeKey:) in the subqueries of the compound query.

In your case you are trying to sort a pointer so it looks like it is not supported by Parse yet..